Trouble with rEFInd: kernel waits for resume device
Moving right along with rEFInd, one issue left: When I boot two of the three automatically created choices, the boot hangs for two minutes as the kernel looks for a resume device.
BTW, to add to the mystery, one of the automatic boot options has no issue with 'resume' -- it seems to find the resume/swap partition by itself.

Try Disabling Hibernation and Fastboot if this dual-boots Windows, the delete the manual entry and use the auto created one.

No Windows here!  100% Debian.

Check your Firmware for Fastboot/Suspend/Hibernate.  Disable them all.  The reason it's hanging is because the device marked for resume has been flagged as "asleep"

Where do I find this firmware?

Your startup firmware/bios/system settings Restart. Press F11 or Del a bunch of times, see if a boot manager comes up.  Choose setup utility etc

Nothing like that on this machine.  Anyway, as I said, one of my automatically found boot options works just fine -- no issues with resume= ... and it also hibernates just fine.  So there's some strange reason why one boot option has trouble and the other one is fine.

Partial answer: I still don't know why, of the three partitions that rEFInd detects and offers for boot, one boots fine and the other two hang waiting for a resume device. However this does fix it: in the two partitions that have the trouble, in their '/boot' directories, create 'refind_linux.conf' and edit them:
"Boot with Standard Options"  "ro root=LABEL=xxxxx resume=LABEL=yyyyy"
... with 'root=...' and 'resume=...' as appropriate. (The default example of that file, found on the EFI partition, created on install of rEFInd, looked like this on my system:
"Boot with standard options"  "ro root=UUID=AC20-A186  "
"Boot to single-user mode"    "ro root=UUID=AC20-A186   single"
"Boot with minimal options"   "ro root=UUID=AC20-A186"

... but it seems that to do anything, the file must live in the same directory as the kernel that is going to boot.  Thus the default example does nothing. (Which is just a well since the UUID above is incorrect.)
